# Bass - shifting fingers

Tags: electric-guitar

Basic question here. Sorry just starting out.

Why switching from finger 2 to 1 on the same B note played (A string)?  Also why the flat indicator?  It wasn’t C# to begin with.  It's like fingers tripping over each other.

From the Bass Method book:

[image]

Comment: What told you it was C# anyway? Hope it wasn't the book.

Comment: @Tim Great catch, no, not in the book.  I meant the B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the same note ^^ it is a **B flat** (the note between A and B), so you play:

| Note | Fret | Finger |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | open | - |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| Bb | 1 | 1 |